# How to add nested list in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have nested list which looks something like this

```
my_list = [[1,'raj','CSE'],[2,'kumar','MECH'],[3,'Nisha','ECE']]
```

Since I need to export this in CSV I want to convert this into a dictionary. My output should be like this.

```
my_dict = {'id':[1,2,3],'Name':['raj','kumar','Nisha'],'Course':['CSE','MECH','ECE']}
```

How can I achieve this???

Comment: What have you tried already to achieve this. Also, are you required to create the expected structure? Because it seems a bit odd to have a dictionary structured that way based on the data.

Comment: Where are you getting the names from?

Comment: You should attempt this problem yourself! I'd suggest a for loop that checks the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd element in each of the nested lists, then assigns them to the proper key in a dictionary you create.

Comment: This is just an example. In the real case, I retrieve data by scraping The Web. There I can only get data in List format

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easily done with `zip`:

```
l = [[1,'raj','CSE'],[2,'kumar','MECH'],[3,'Nisha','ECE']]
d = dict(zip(['Id', 'Name', 'Course'], map(list, (zip(*l))))) 
d    
# {'Course': ['CSE', 'MECH', 'ECE'],
#  'Id': [1, 2, 3],
#  'Name': ['raj', 'kumar', 'Nisha']}
```

Since you want to convert it to a dict first before saving it to a csv, I'm assuming you use pandas (otherwise it'd have been easier to save it in its existing form). This is easily done:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)  # `d` is from the code snippet above.

df

  Course  Id   Name
0    CSE   1    raj
1   MECH   2  kumar
2    ECE   3  Nisha

df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

---

Alternatively, if you *don't* want to use pandas, just do this:

```
l = [[1,'raj','CSE'],[2,'kumar','MECH'],[3,'Nisha','ECE']]
 with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerow(['Id', 'Name', 'Course'])
     writer.writerows(l)
```

In this situation, you do not require conversion to a dictionary.

Comment: @Wondercricket Indeed it does! Thanks, I tried this on python 3 only, wasn't sure if it'd work otherwise :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Coldspeed's very elegant solution:

```
headers = ['id', 'Name', 'Course']
my_list = [[1,'raj','CSE'],[2,'kumar','MECH'],[3,'Nisha','ECE']]
my_dict = {k: [x[i] for x in my_list] for i, k in enumerate(headers)}
print(my_dict)  # {'Name': ['raj', 'kumar', 'Nisha'], 'Course': ['CSE', 'MECH', 'ECE'], 'id': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to export it to csv, Pandas is quite handy:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['id','Name','Course']).to_csv("Name.csv")
```

Comment: That seems overkill to have to require an installation of pandas for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and elegant way to me is by `zip` function:

```
my_list = [[1,'raj','CSE'],[2,'kumar','MECH'],[3,'Nisha','ECE']]
ids, names, courses = map(list, zip(*my_list))
my_dict = {'id': ids, 'Name': names, 'Course': courses}
```

Comment: i don't refresh the answers when i read the other answers. I don't delete beacause i think my solution is more readable

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple:

```
my_dict={
         'id':[a[0] for a in my_list],
         'Name': [a[1] for a in my_list],
         'Course':[a[2] for a in my_list]
        }
```